# Xcode Custom UIView Not Displaying Properly

Tags: xcode, uiview, interface-builder, uistackview

I have created a custom UIView A which is embedded into another custom UIView B because I want to reuse views.

(Cannot post more than 2 images so omitted)

The swift code I used is as follows:

```
override init(frame: CGRect)
{
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupView()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setupView()
}

private func setupView()
{
    let view = viewFromNibForClass()
    view.autoresizingMask = [
        .flexibleWidth,
        .flexibleHeight
    ]
    view.frame = bounds
    addSubview(view)
}

private func viewFromNibForClass() -> UIView
{
    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    let nib = UINib(nibName: String(describing: type(of: self)), bundle: bundle)
    let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView
    return view
}
```

When placing several UIView A (in a stack) into UIView B, the **views will randomly jump** to the top left of the superview, sometimes out of the view frame. I have to change the resizing mask temporarily into this:

```
view.autoresizingMask = [
        .flexibleWidth,
        .flexibleHeight,
        .flexibleTopMargin,
        .flexibleBottomMargin,
        .flexibleLeftMargin,
        .flexibleRightMargin
    ]
```

then change it back after the adjustments have been made. But still, I am **unable to apply any simple constraints like height or distance to superview.leading without encountering multiple conflicts**.

[Custom UIView B containing several UIView A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ov4A.png)

To resolve all the conflicts, I have to delete every constraint and proceed. Then, putting UIView B into a view controller in my main storyboard, again will cause the view to jump to some weird position. I believe this is attributed to the abnormal behaviour of UIView A outlined in the first query.

[Generic view controller containing UIView B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4KIf.png)

Thanks for any help or pointers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After scrutinising every file (short of deleting and starting from scratch), I realised that the XIB file had a custom class referencing itself in the Identity Inspector. This had probably caused it to call upon its `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` recursively and thus its position went out of whack. Did not detect this earlier as I had been using the custom views without Autolayout and everything was fine. And yes the file's owner of the XIB was set correctly. Removed the mistake and all was good.